# Inserting a record into Top of Table

Tags: t-sql, insert, ssms

Hopefully an easy question for someone with more experience than me. I have a stored procedure that Inserts records into a table. Like all databases that I have worked with, when you insert a record it inserts it into the bottom of the table. I would like to insert it to the top of the table and then move all the existing records down by one (I assume this would happen automatically with the insert).

I want to to do this because I'm using the 'Top #' keyword. I am pretty sure that I could just leave it the way it is, and instead of using the 'Top" keyword, I could use the 'Bottom" keyword. But I want to make it easier for people reading it that aren't familiar with it, so they can instantly see the newest entries. I'm going to keep researching this on my own, but If someone knew off the top of their head and could save me the time that would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "move all the existing records down by one"? There's no such thing as `top` or `bottom` in a table; you define the order by which the records are sorted, and `top` takes the top X records from that sorted resultset.

Comment: You should use `top ()` combined with `order by SomeColumn desc`. There is no order of rows in a table. You specify the order you want in a query.

Comment: Just realized i posted the same answer as @MikaelEriksson and LittleBobbyTables did in their comments, so I deleted it

Comment: The answer looks good. Undelete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there any incremental id on that table.If yes then create clustered index on that id  with descending order